# {"detail":"'state' parameter in callback request does not match our internal 'state', someone may be trying to do something bad."}

Tags: python, fastapi

I am working on code to login to my app using Microsoft login using fastapi. I am able to call microsoft login page and after entering the login credentials i am getting the error "{"detail":"'state' parameter in callback request does not match our internal 'state', someone may be trying to do something bad."}"

```
**main.py**

from fastapi_sso.sso.microsoft import MicrosoftSSO
app1 = FastAPI()

microsoft_sso = MicrosoftSSO("client-id", "client-secret", "http://localhost:8000/dashboard")

@app1.get("/microsoft/login")
async def microsoft_login():
    return await microsoft_sso.get_login_redirect() 

@app1.get("/dashboard")
async def microsoft_callback(request: Request):
    user_new = await microsoft_sso.verify_and_process(request) #getting error at this point
    print(user_new.id)
    print("Hello Microsoftttttttttttttttt")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with this SOO using the google one. The solution  was to create a new pair of keys and use one when developing the platform locally and the other one being used only in production. After doing this, the issue faded away. Just like that.

Comment: I am using the 'generic' option in fastapi-sso.   I am getting same msg:  "detail": "'state' parameter in callback request does not match our internal 'state', someone may be trying to do something bad."    I only have one dev env.   Can you elaborate how setting 2 env may solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to pass `use_state=False` in the SSO constructor:

```
microsoft_sso = MicrosoftSSO("client-id", "client-secret", "http://localhost:8000/dashboard", use_state=False)
```

If the application is distributed (i.e multiple web servers), or if it plans to handle multiple simultaneous SSO flows (i.e login request for user A, then login request for user B, then callback for A then callback for B), then the default `use_state=True` is a bad idea. No idea how much more secure is it, but the above reasons are enough for me to disable this "feature".

What it does is, when generating the redirect url it generates a `state`, stores it locally and passes it as a cookie to provider, then in callback it checks if the cookie matches local `state`.